# quotient ring of the class $C^{\infty}$ functions on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, formal-power-series

Let $I$ be an ideal of the ring of smooth functions $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ defined by $$I=\left\{f\in\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})\,:\,f^{(n)}(0)=0~\textrm{for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge0}$}\right\}.$$ Then, $I$ is a prime ideal of $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$.

What is the isomorphic image of the quotient ring $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})/I$?

Which domain can be considerd as an isomorphic image of $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})/I$?

Comment: Well, your choice of tags seems to suggest you already know the answer, or at least have a guess...

Comment: @EricWofsey, It's just a tag. I have no idea ;(